# Разница между --deployment и --no-deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Не совсем понимаю разницу между `--deployment` и `--no-deployment`.
В каких случаях нужно делать одно, в каких другое?

Или, например, например можно ли сделать в production среде просто `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install`

К примеру в `Gemfile` добавил новый гем, задеплоил, в production что нужно сделать? (использую capistrano 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно Cpistrano выполняет команду `bundle install --deployment` автоматически и никаких пост-действий на сервере выполнять не требуется. Выполнять руками `bundle install --deployment` не следует. Локально параметр `--no-deployment` действует по умолчанию и используется только если вы по ошибке выполнили `bundle install --deployment`, обычно `bundle` об этом вас сам попросит в консоли.

Порядок действий при добавлении нового гема следующий. Вы добавляете гем, локально выполняете `bundle install` (можно просто `bundle`, `install` — действие по умолванию), чтобы новая информация из Gemfile была добавлена в Gemfile.lock. Изменения забрасываете в репозиторий, чтобы Capistrano имел возможность загрузить их на сервер. Только после этого выполняете деплой.

Бывает, что у вас есть какие-то уникальные задачи, которые нужно выполнить в процессе деплоя, в этом случае вы создаете cap-задачу (rake-задача в lib/capistrano/tasks) и встраиваете ее в capflow. Однако, для выполнения `bunlde` на сервере, уже есть стандартная cap-задача, более того, она уже встроена в capflow, нужно только убедиться, что все подключено правильно.

Для того, чтобы все работало корректно, убедитесь, что у вас в файле Capfile имеется строка

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Она добавит в capflow задачу `deploy:bundle` после стадии `deploy:updated`

```
deploy
  deploy:starting
    [before]
      deploy:ensure_stage
      deploy:set_shared_assets
    deploy:check
  deploy:started
  deploy:updating
    git:create_release
    deploy:symlink:shared
  deploy:updated
    [before]
      deploy:bundle
    [after]
      deploy:migrate
      deploy:compile_assets
      deploy:normalize_assets
  deploy:publishing
    deploy:symlink:release
  deploy:published
  deploy:finishing
    deploy:cleanup
  deploy:finished
    deploy:log_revision
```

Возможно вам так же будет интересна [Flow-часть документации Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/)